# How can I write the command on Databricks to read XML file (based on Python code)?

Tags: python, xml, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Supposed that I have this kind of xml structure:

```
<xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<a>
    <title = "Kurosaki Ichigo"
            tel = "123-456, 234-567"
          class = "Employee"
             id = "EM-02"/>
    <title = "Abarai Renji"
            tel = "345-678, 456-789"
          class = "Employee"
             id = "EM-03"/>
    <title = "Aizen Sosuke"
            tel = "567-890, 012-345"
          class = "Employee"
             id = "EM-04"/>
</a>
```

I want to let Databricks (Pyspark) read this data. How can I set up the options and other parameters?

Comment: That's not valid XML.

Comment: https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/ ?

Comment: Databricks - Read - XML Docs - https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/xml.html#language-scala

Answer (score 0):

For Reading XML file .Please follow below syntax:

Make sure to check and install `com.databricks:spark-xml` for reading XML file.

[image: Ref1]

> **Sample XML**

```
<catalog>
<book id="bk101" name="vv" address="hyd">
    
<author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
<title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
<genre>Computer</genre>
<price>44.95</price>
<publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
<description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
</book>
</catalog>
```

> **Reading XML file**

```
df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag", "book").load("dbfs:/FileStore/xmlvalidator.xml")  
    display(df)
```

[image]