# Trying to save an xml string output to an xml file in adls using Azure Synapse Notebooks Pyspark

Tags: xml, pyspark, azure-synapse

I am calling an api which sends back an xml string as its response. I am trying to take that xml string and save it as an xml file in ADLS using pyspark in Azure Synapse Notebooks. From there I am then trying to read that xml file and convert it to parquet.

I was able to successfully call the api address and get the xml string as a response, however when trying to write out the file or read an xml file using the below logic I am met with the following error.

`df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").options(rowTag="message").load("<adls_file_path>")`

*error* - `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1744.load. : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.xml`

Answer (score 0):

The above error mainly happens because of libraries are properly not installed.

**Please follow below steps:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Download a jar file [click here](https://libraries.io/maven/com.databricks:spark-xml_2.12)

Follow below **reference** for more information:

- [How can I write the command on Databricks to read XML file (based on Python code)? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73604490/how-can-i-write-the-command-on-databricks-to-read-xml-file-based-on-python-code/73631835#73631835)
- [XML Data Source for Apache Spark](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml)
- [Read and Write XML files in PySpark by Raymond](https://kontext.tech/article/369/read-xml-files-in-pyspark)